# Comparison script in 2 databases

Tags: sql, database, dynamic-sql

I am trying to write a comparison script against my play and live database to figure out if I have certain data attributes missing from either live or test environment. IDs generally don't match. Data Attributes are from several different tables.

```
(Select T1.ID,T1.Description, T1.Type, T1.Environment
from
(select cast(current_timestamp as varchar(50)) as id, 'Core Data As Of' as description, '_Extract Date' as type, 'PLAY' as Environment
union
select cast(id as varchar(50))as id, first_name +' '+ last_name as description, 'Salereps' as type, 'PLAY' as Environment from zACdb3.dbo.contacts where salesrep = 'Y' and delete_flag = 'N'
union
select cast(id as varchar(50))as id, first_name +' '+ last_name as description, 'Buyers' as type, 'PLAY' as Environment from zACdb3.dbo.contacts where buyer ='Y' and delete_flag = 'N'
union
select cast(terms_id as varchar(50)) as id, terms_desc as description, 'Terms' as type, 'PLAY' as Environment from zACdb3.dbo.terms where delete_flag = 'N'
) T1 --ORDER BY T1.Type, T1.ID, T1.Description, T1.Environment ASC

union all 

Select T2.ID, T2.Description, T2.Type, T2.Environment
From
(select cast(current_timestamp as varchar(50)) as id, 'Core Data As Of' as description, '_Extract Date' as type, 'LIVE' as Environment
union
select cast(id as varchar(50))as id, first_name +' '+ last_name as description, 'Salereps' as type, 'LIVE' as Environment from zACdb1.dbo.contacts where salesrep = 'Y' and delete_flag = 'N'
union
select cast(id as varchar(50))as id, first_name +' '+ last_name as description, 'Buyers' as type, 'LIVE' as Environment from zACdb1.dbo.contacts where buyer ='Y' and delete_flag = 'N'
union
select cast(terms_id as varchar(50)) as id, terms_desc as description, 'Terms' as type, 'LIVE' as Environment from zACdb1.dbo.terms where delete_flag = 'N'
) T2 --ORDER BY T2.Type, T2.ID, T2.Description, T2.Environment ASC 
--Order by t1.Type, T1.Description, T1.ID, T1.Environment
)

Except
(
/*) T3

Union ALL

Select T6.ID,T6.Description, T6.Type, T6.Environment
from(*/
Select T1.ID,T1.Description, T1.Type, T1.Environment
from
(select cast(current_timestamp as varchar(50)) as id, 'Core Data As Of' as description, '_Extract Date' as type, 'PLAY' as Environment
union
select cast(id as varchar(50))as id, first_name +' '+ last_name as description, 'Salereps' as type, 'PLAY' as Environment from zACdb3.dbo.contacts where salesrep = 'Y' and delete_flag = 'N'
union
select cast(id as varchar(50))as id, first_name +' '+ last_name as description, 'Buyers' as type, 'PLAY' as Environment from zACdb3.dbo.contacts where buyer ='Y' and delete_flag = 'N'
union
select cast(terms_id as varchar(50)) as id, terms_desc as description, 'Terms' as type, 'PLAY' as Environment from zACdb3.dbo.terms where delete_flag = 'N'
) T1 

INTERSECT

Select T2.ID, T2.Description, T2.Type, T2.Environment
From
(select cast(current_timestamp as varchar(50)) as id, 'Core Data As Of' as description, '_Extract Date' as type, 'LIVE' as Environment
union
select cast(id as varchar(50))as id, first_name +' '+ last_name as description, 'Salereps' as type, 'LIVE' as Environment from zACdb1.dbo.contacts where salesrep = 'Y' and delete_flag = 'N'
union
select cast(id as varchar(50))as id, first_name +' '+ last_name as description, 'Buyers' as type, 'LIVE' as Environment from zACdb1.dbo.contacts where buyer ='Y' and delete_flag = 'N'
union
select cast(terms_id as varchar(50)) as id, terms_desc as description, 'Terms' as type, 'LIVE' as Environment from zACdb1.dbo.terms where delete_flag = 'N'
) T2
) Order by t1.type, t1.description, t1.id, t1.Environment
```

Ideally would like to see something like this. Know Im not there but not sure how to get there when IDS don't match but the description and type should match

```
| ID     | Type     |Play    |  Live
| 1001   | SalesRep |Joe Buck|  Missing
| 1003   | Buyer    |Missing |  Ty Wood
```

Comment: If you add a tag for your specific DBMS, such as [sql-server], [oracle], [mysql], etc., you will reach a larger audience including those who specialize in the specific DBMS you are working on.